# Python Script Runs and Shows 0 Errors, But the output is not produced

Tags: python, pdf, merge

I created a script in python that takes pdf and a pdf with a watermark, merges them together and creates a new file with the result. However, I can successfully run the script with no errors but no new file with the merged pdfs are created. I printed a "done" to make sure it ran through it and the done printed yet no merged pdf.

```
import PyPDF2

template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('super.pdf', 'rb'))
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('wtr.pdf', 'rb'))
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter

for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
    page = template.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

    with open('watermarked_output.pdf', 'wb') as file:
        output.write(file)

print("done")
```

I expected to get a merged pdf with the watermark on each page. Instead I got no new file. Just a message stating the script ran.

Comment: As a first debugging step, print the result of `template.getNumPages()` -- if this is 0, the for loop won't run at all, which would explain the problem.

Comment: Why is powershell tagged? Shouldn't `PdfFileWriter` have an open close parentheses: `()`?